# Redirect to another page when fatal error occurs

Tags: php, php-7.2

I'm receiving the following fatal error on an application that I'm currently working on.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 1245184 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line
>   7317
>
> Warning: unlink(./Logo.jpg): No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line
>   7801

What I want to do is redirect to another page when a fatal error occurs. The following is the code I'm playing around with but no luck.

```
set_time_limit(0);
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

try {
    ...
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        header('Location: http://localhost:8080/docs/generate.php'); exit;
}
```

The issue over here is that the redirection doesn't happen on fatal error.

Please advise.

Comment: I think it's imposible. When you use all of available memory, there is no way to execute more instructions, event create new Throwable object to represent exception.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot catch fatal errors in PHP. But there's a workaround that can be useful in your case.

You can register a callback on shutdown using [`register_shutdown_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.php'; // use ABSOLUTE path
    die();
});
```

You may wonder redirecting users to another page using [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) instead of including `file.php` and stopping the execution of script. Well, you'll get a warning:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Since you cannot send any HTTP header in the shutdown callback.

Comment: from php.net - "If you want to do something with files in function, that registered in register_shutdown_function(), use ABSOLUTE paths to files instead of relative. Because when script processing is complete current working directory chages to ServerRoot" So when redirecting we would need something like - require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/full path to file/file.php');die;